# I have a Error to add @Entity data annotation to class android for room database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-room

My friends from the Android site I copied the dependencies related to room in Gradle but I can not add Dataantotaion related to Entity to the class and after add @Entity it has Error "Canot resolve symbol 'Entity'
I use Java android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$Versionroom"
```

To

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$Versionroom"
```

And add

```
javaCompileOptions {
annotationProcessorOptions {
    includeCompileClasspath = true
    }
  }
```

hope this help you fix the symbol resolving problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add room dependencies and annotationProcessor dependencies for it Try is :

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```